# Getting Average per column from Arraylist with unknown quantity of columns

Tags: java, arraylist

How do you get an average of multiple columns in an array list without knowing the quantity of  columns? i.e.

```
1    2    3    4    5    6
9    2    3    4    5    6
1    2    7    4    8    6
1    9    3    8    5    5
```

Getting the average for all columns, 1+9+1+1/4 so on?

Comment: You have to iterate all elements, in your example you will get the average of the first column.. you have to use 2 for statements so you can iterate through rows and columns

Comment: You should make your question more specific, as it is now it is very difficult to know how your data is represented. This is very important as the structure determines how one looks for the elements.

Comment: You know the length is `array.length`

Comment: 1+9+1+1/4 will not calculate the average of 1, 9, 1 and 1. (1+9+1+1)/4 will.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I assume that you are dealing with a 2D array?

If that is the case, then you can make a double-for-loop and access the columns like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < array[].length; j++) {
        //add whichever row or column you are looking for    
    }
}
```

You should also keep to different counters for how many columns and rows there are when dividing.

Comment: I need to calculate the average of every column

Comment: @CBH, the outer for-loop loops over the rows. The inner loops over columns. That should give you enough information to calculate the average by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

This is easy if you have an array that has equal row length for the entire table. Suppose that your data is in a int array[][]. Then the number of rows is array.length and you can find the number of column with array[0].length. If you fix on one column (without checking for correct array dimensions) :

```
public static double getColumnAverage( int array[][], int column ) {
   int sum = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
      sum += array[ i ][ column ];
   return sum / (double) array.length; 
}
```